# Why is xcode 4.3 failing to Archive my app?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode is failing to Archive my app for distribution, with the following error message:

```
SetOwnerAndGroup "myusername:staff" /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-fqcgjdalayjdsffpmgzhzjmgadmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/armv7
    cd /Volumes/MEDIA/Dropbox/Code/ios/AppName
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH "myusername:staff" /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-fqcgjdalayjdsffpmgzhzjmgadmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/armv7

chown: /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-fqcgjdalayjdsffpmgzhzjmgadmn/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/armv7: No such file or directory
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

System:

- OSX Lion (10.7.3)
- XCode (4.3)
- Target: iOS 4.0 and iOS 5.0

**Update**

I've got a work around for now, I changed my architecture from:

```
armv7 armv6
```

to

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) armv6
```

Answer (score 2):

search for a rogue 'armv6' somewhere in your build settings. For me it was under 'Alternate File Permissions' under the Deployment section. Had the same error and this cleared it up. Others I've seen suggested is in the 'Other C Flag' section.